# How do I delete kubernetes resources on a local deploy?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I am attempting to remove all resources from my local k8 deploy.  I have tried individual deletes, bulk deletes, and delete all.  I have deleted replica sets and deployments.  No matter what I do, everything auto recreates itself instantly.  How do I actually get rid of all this without having to hard reset k8?

Comment: Can you post your yaml code?

Comment: Please elaborate more on what all commands you tried and what output it gives. We can't answer this until we have sufficient details.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there are some custom resources? Run a quick `kubectl get crd` to see if any CRDs are installed in your cluster. Try deleting them. When there's a controller listen for these CRDs it will re-create the resources instantly. In addition, you could run a `kubectl get pods --all-namespaces` and look, if you see any controller (mostly named something like `<APPNAME>-controller-<SOMETHING>` and delete them.

Another solution could be to delete the namespace (If your apps do not live in the default Namespace).